# Linq to sql take skip and overall count

Tags: linq-to-sql

Take a query

```
dim q = from i in db.test select i.name
```

Now I use `count` to get the complete number of the items.
I use them to get a pager control:

```
dim count = q.count
```

Then I use `take` and `skip` to get my records.

This produces two queries and I wonder if there is a possibility to get the count of all items but to select only 10 of them so that l2s produces just one query.

The columns would then look like:

`allcount` - `name`

This query would give me 10 items, but in the column allcount would be the complete number of all items.

Answer (score 0):

try using 'new' statement; it always works for me :)

```
var _data = from i in db.test select new { count = i.name.count(), records = i.name };
```

You can also see my blog on basic LINQ to SQL queries: [LinqtoSQL](http://wahabkotwal.blogspot.com/2011/05/taste-of-linq-to-sql.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: i know the new statement, but if you read my question again, maybe you will see that this absolutly will not solve the problem